# Executor cannot be shutdown from the Thread acquired from itself

Tags: java, multithreading, netty, ning

Hi guys : This question involves threads, clients, Netty, and Ning.

CONTEXT

The Ning library is an Asynchronous HTTP request tool which allows us to build requests, queue them, and handle them asynchronously.  It relies on some libraries, such as the JBoss/Netty code pasted below.

PROBLEM

I recently ran across a Thread closing exception which was thrown by this bit of code in the JBoss/Netty `ExecutorUtil` class.

This class appears to be essentially a utility for ending threads in Netty.

This method was causing a bug in a web client (powered by Ning) that I was using, by the fact that I was attempting to close an HttpClient inside of a handler for that client's response.

**Question**

What is the significance of the deadlock this block of code is attempting to avoid ? For further details, the class can be seen at [this code url](http://grepcode.com/file_/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.ning/metrics.goodwill-access/0.1.4/org/jboss/netty/util/internal/ExecutorUtil.java/?v=source).

```
// Check dead lock.
    final Executor currentParent = DeadLockProofWorker.PARENT.get();
    if (currentParent != null) {
        for (Executor e: executorsCopy) {
            if (e == currentParent) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(
                        "An Executor cannot be shut down from the thread " +
                        "acquired from itself.  Please make sure you are " +
                        "not calling releaseExternalResources() from an " +
                        "I/O worker thread.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In netty you are not allowed to shutdown the Executor from within an IO-Thread (as the exception is telling you already ;)), this is because you would have the risk of see a deadlock. If you really want to shutdown the Executor from within a handler you need to do it in a new thread. Something like for example:

```
public void messageReceived(...) {
    // in IO-Thread
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            //....shutdown here
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: How does the separation of threads prevent deadlock.?  I would imagine that the same problem exists if we call close from an external thread..? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Netty calls ExecutorService.shutdown() to terminate the executor which returns when all submitted tasks have finished. You can't shutdown the executor from an IO-Thread because ExecutorService.shutdown() will wait for the IO-Thread which has called shutdown to return. The result is deadlock. Norman's suggestion works because the new thread is free to wait until all IO-Threads have returned.